# Solr cloud Swap collection alias

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to implement Active / Passive data collection on Solr cloud. We get a new feed file everyday, I have created 2 collections of similar config Col1 and Col2 with alias Col_active and Col_passive pointing to actual collections. Every night I want to load the feed file to passive and switch alias after successful load, so there will not be a long downtime.

> Col_active -> Col1, Col_passive -> Col2

After successful load to Col_passive, swap Col_active and Col_passive such that

> Col_active -> Col2, Col_passive -> Col1

Like SWAP action for Core API, is there a straight-forward way to swap Collection alias pls let me know or is there any other better way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: How is the data designed to be accessed? By a webapp? By a program?

Comment: By Web application

Comment: Then an easier way would probably be once you've updated the other core, just change the core that the webapp is querying. That way it's pretty much instant (or even if you have to reset the webapp that's only probably less than 30 seconds).

Changing the names/aliases of the collections sounds like a lot more hassle and it'd be good to have them nice and distinct so you can keep track of which is which.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multiple clients pointing to this service. So the change has to be made in multiple clients by different teams. That's the reason for this alias to the change is transparent to the client.

Answer (score 3):

As of now there is no such straightforward collection API.

But you could achieve the same by doing the 2 API calls

> admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name= Col_active&collections= Col2
>   admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name= Col_passive&collections= Col1